# SeekBar/Slider with different step sizes

Tags: android, slider, seekbar, android-seekbar

I am building a Slider or SeekBar with different step sizes. What I want is a SeekBar range from 10 - 3500 but with only 7 Steps i.e., 10, 200, 500, 1000, 2000, 3500. So, you can see the step size is not constant.

It would be great if anyone can give idea on this ?